# Nginx routing with Docker Rails 5 Postgres app

Tags: postgresql, nginx, docker, docker-compose, ruby-on-rails-5

When I tried to Dockerize Rails app into container and run Nginx on host I got problem with routing from outside in. 
I can't access /public in rails app container. Instead I can see  `/var/www/app/public` at host.

How can I route from Nginx to Docker Rails container?

**nginx.conf:**

```
upstream puma_app {
  server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

server {

  listen 80;

  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;

  error_page 500 502 504 /500.html;
  error_page 503 @503;

  server_name localhost app;
  root /var/www/app/public;
  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma_app;

  location @puma_app {

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_pass http://puma_app;
    # limit_req zone=one;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
  }

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  location = /50x.html {
    root html;
  }

  location = /404.html {
    root html;
  }

  location @503 {
    error_page 405 = /system/maintenance.html;
    if (-f $document_root/system/maintenance.html) {
      rewrite ^(.*)$ /system/maintenance.html break;
    }
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /503.html break;
  }
   if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|PUT|PATCH|POST|DELETE|OPTIONS)$ ){
    return 405;
 }

 if (-f $document_root/system/maintenance.html) {
  return 503;
 }

 location ~ \.(php|html)$ {
  return 405;
 }
}
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '2'

services:
  app:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
    volumes:
      - 'app:/var/www/app'
      - 'public:/var/www/app/public'
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    env_file:
      - '.env'
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: 'postgres_user'
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - 'postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data'

volumes:
  postgres:
  app:
  public:
```

**Dockerfile**

```
# Base image:
FROM ruby:2.4

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs

# Set an environment variable where the Rails app is installed to inside of Docker image:
ENV RAILS_ROOT /var/www/app
RUN mkdir -p $RAILS_ROOT

ENV RAILS_ENV production
ENV RACK_ENV production

# Set working directory, where the commands will be ran:
WORKDIR $RAILS_ROOT

# Gems:
COPY Gemfile Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock Gemfile.lock
RUN gem install bundler
RUN bundle install

COPY config/puma.rb config/puma.rb

# Copy the main application.
COPY . .

RUN bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production assets:precompile

VOLUME ["$RAILS_ROOT/public"]

EXPOSE 3000

# The default command that gets ran will be to start the Puma server.
CMD bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
```

Comment: Can you explain this line better way: `I can't access /public in rails app container. Instead I can see /var/www/app/public at host.` Specially the second statement. I have not yet been able to understand it.

Comment: I cloned whole app to `/var/www/app` and then ran docker-compose. So I think Nginx should route to `/var/www/app` which is inside container but now it routes to `/var/www/app` at host. So app can't load assets because compiled assets are in container not in cloned app.

Comment: I think both should be same. If you cloned inside the container while the host directory was mounted, then it should be present in host also. I think that the host directories are not getting mounted properly. You could try by providing direct paths

Comment: No, why would I clone inside container? I copied whole app inside Dockerfile by `COPY . .`  I also add Dockerfile to complete whole picture

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to access `/public` from host inside the container at `/var/www/app/public`.

You need to mount host directory inside container. You can use `-v "/public:/var/www/app/public"` while running the container.

Comment: I got volumes `- 'public:/var/www/app/public'` inside my docker-compose.yml

Comment: I added whole docker-compose.yml for more info

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with your `Dockerfile`. I'm not sure how you want to setup your docker image, but it seem like you try to use a `public` directory in a docker volume; I would suggest to store the compiled assets into the docker image itself. This way, you can sure that the assets are always together with the image.

You current `Dockerfile` should run the `assets:precompile` before the `COPY . .`; Meaning the assets should be compiled into the `public` directory first before copying it into the docker image.

Anyhow, you should try a running a really simple docker app first before using it on a more complex project setup, here's a [blog post](http://codingnudge.com/2017/03/17/tutorial-how-to-run-ruby-on-rails-on-docker-part-1/) that might help you (disclaimer: I wrote that post)

Answer (score 0):

In docker, every container has it's own IP address and are not `local` to each other. So you can't use `127.0.0.1` ip in the Nginx container as ip of the Rails container. Fortunately docker containers can be linked together using their service names. So you must replace change your upstream to

```
upstream puma_app {
  server http://app:3000;
}
```

Also you should add Nginx container to your docker-compose file (suppose your nginx conf files are in `config/nginx/conf.d` dir):

```
version: '2'

services:
  app:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
    volumes:
      - app:/var/www/app
      - public:/var/www/app/public
      - nginx-confs:/var/www/app/config/nginx/conf.d
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    env_file: .env
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres_user
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - nginx-confs:/etc/nginx/conf.d

volumes:
  postgres:
  app:
  public:
  nginx-confs:
```